# Clearing mock location data in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, locationmanager

I have mock location set in my app but when I try to clear it and get my real location using the setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true) button I a get weird error like:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: test.test.location, PID: 9617
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative latSpan: -1.3741614700601624E-5
at maps.ce.i.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ei.bs.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ei.v.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ei.v.onClick(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
```

When I get my real location first before trying to set a mock location it works fine. But when I set a mock location then clear it and get my real location it produces this error. So somehow there must be bits of mock location data interfering.

My code to clear the mock location data is:

```
locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName,false);
locationManager.clearTestProviderEnabled(providerName);
locationManager.clearTestProviderLocation(providerName);
locationManager.clearTestProviderStatus(providerName);
locationManager.removeTestProvider(providerName);
```

I can't find any documentation on how to properly clear mock location data so I'm searching for answers here.

Comment: Can you share your code so that we can also test it?